# Specify gradle configuration or customize dependencies in bootJar task?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Our application is using EclipseLink. For production artifacts we use static weaving, we have a Gradle task that builds a separate jar that should be included in the Spring Boot fat jar. During development we are not using weaving so we don't have this artifact.

What we would like to do is customize the classpath in the bootJar task so that we include the weaved artifact and exclude the source of the un-weaved module. Prior to 2.0.x of the Spring Boot Gradle plugin this was achieved by specifying a customConfiguration in a task of type bootRepackage, like this:

```
task singleJar(type: BootRepackage) {
  customConfiguration = "weavedRuntime"
}
```

But this option seems to be missing in the 2.0.x version. Is there any way of overriding the configuration in the new version?

Alternatively we need to modify the classpath, but just for the bootJar task. The  normal runtime classpath shoukd include the un-weaved module, but the bootJar classpath should include the weaved artifact and exclude the un-weaved module. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: did you find a solution?